# How do I connect a crossfilter(ed) dataset to a d3 chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, crossfilter

I have succesfully created a crossfilter object using my existing dataset, created a dimension and added a filter:

```
var calendarData = crossfilter([
{start_date: "2015-07-01",end_date: "2015-09-01",Channel: "Twitter"}, 
{start_date: "2015-07-01",end_date: "2015-07-24",Channel: "Twitter"}, 
{start_date: "2015-07-15",end_date: "2015-09-01",Channel: "Twitter"}, 
{start_date: "2015-08-05",end_date: "2015-09-24",Channel: "Facebook"}, 
{start_date: "2015-08-05",end_date: "2015-08-10",Channel: "Facebook"}
]);

// create dimension, based on Channel    

var calendarDataByChannel = calendarData.dimension(function(d) { return d.Channel; });

// filter by Twitter    

var calendarDataFilter = calendarDataByChannel.filter("Twitter");
```

I then create an svg and try to append rectangles and whatnot as per normal d3 functionality, referencing the crossfilter:

```
var rectangles = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(calendarData)
    .enter();
```

But it doesn't work. What is the correct method for connecting to the crossfiltered data?

I don't want to use dc.js for this project and all the examples I can find generally relate to dc.

Thanks,
Keith

Comment: Can you put your full code on a fiddle ... even if its not working.

Comment: did you try data(calendarData.bottom(Infinity)) ?

Comment: Here's an ugly version of what I'm trying to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/duncanklf/besLh1pu/ and here's what I have with the crossfilter: https://jsfiddle.net/duncanklf/nvg5e7eb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two lines of changes:

Your code

```
var calendarDataFilter = calendarDataByChannel.filter("Twitter");
```

It should have been:

```
var calendarDataFilter = calendarDataByChannel.filter("Twitter").top(Infinity);
```

Next your code:

```
var rectangles = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(calendarData)
    .enter();
```

Should have been

```
var rectangles = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(calendarDataFilter)
    .enter();
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/zxvmje3q/1/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great! Thanks Cyril. Perfect!

Comment: While this does work, it's usually not very idiomatic Crossfilter. If `dim` is your Crossfilter dimension, it's more common to use `.data(dim.top(Infinity))` to set the data of your d3 selection. This way, when you do updates you will get the dimension values for the current filters.

Answer (score 0):

Dimensions and filters in Crossfilter are stateful. So the log in the last line here will be `true`.

```
var calendarData = crossfilter([
{start_date: "2015-07-01",end_date: "2015-09-01",Channel: "Twitter"}, 
{start_date: "2015-07-01",end_date: "2015-07-24",Channel: "Twitter"}, 
{start_date: "2015-07-15",end_date: "2015-09-01",Channel: "Twitter"}, 
{start_date: "2015-08-05",end_date: "2015-09-24",Channel: "Facebook"}, 
{start_date: "2015-08-05",end_date: "2015-08-10",Channel: "Facebook"}
]);   

var calendarDataByChannel = calendarData.dimension(function(d) { return d.Channel; });   
var calendarDataFilter = calendarDataByChannel.filter("Twitter");
console.lot(calendarDataByChannel === calendarDataFilter);
```

The idiomatic way to write this would be more like

```
var calendarData = crossfilter([
{start_date: "2015-07-01",end_date: "2015-09-01",Channel: "Twitter"}, 
{start_date: "2015-07-01",end_date: "2015-07-24",Channel: "Twitter"}, 
{start_date: "2015-07-15",end_date: "2015-09-01",Channel: "Twitter"}, 
{start_date: "2015-08-05",end_date: "2015-09-24",Channel: "Facebook"}, 
{start_date: "2015-08-05",end_date: "2015-08-10",Channel: "Facebook"}
]);

// create dimension, based on Channel    

var calendarDataByChannel = calendarData.dimension(function(d) { return d.Channel; });

// filter by Twitter    

calendarDataByChannel.filter("Twitter");

var rectangles = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(calendarDataByChannel.top(Infinity))
    .enter();
```

There are pretty good Crossfilter tutorials you might want to take a look at, like: http://blog.rusty.io/2012/09/17/crossfilter-tutorial/  Asking here also works :-)